# flush_rewrite_rules() not working on plugin activation

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am experimenting with creating a simple plugin to create a custom post type named project but am having some trouble with the rewrite rules not been flushed on activation.

I have the main plugin file with this function:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'Project_Custom_Post_Type::activate' );
```

Then within my class I have this:

```
public function activate() {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

My class has a construct of:

```
public function __construct() {
  add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_type' ), 0 );
}
```

I cannot see why it is not working? My deactivation flush works fine.

Comment: `'Project_Custom_Post_Type::activate'` is not a valid callable type in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not read as a callback. You should pass an array:

```
$pcpt = new Project_Custom_Post_Type;
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $pcpt, 'activate' ) );
```

Note that `init` happens **before** plugin activation, so not callbacks from your class will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

On activation, the "init" action has already run. So your flush is actually taking place just fine, but your post type is not being registered before the flush takes place. Add the code to register your post type to your activation function, before you flush the rewrite rules.

Also, yes, your activation hook call is incorrect, as toscho pointed out.

Comment: Ok so I now have it working with this:

`register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $project, 'activate' ) );`

With my activate function including this line:

`$this->my_register_post_type();`

All works great.

I still have the `my_register_post_type();` function being called on 'init' also.

I presume it needs to be called in both places?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in both places.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a direct answer to this question. However, I've seen multiple workarounds for dealing with this issue ( `flush_rewrite_rules()` being executed first ).

A workaround was to set a flag ( using `add_option()` ) and then hook to the `init`, and flush the rewrite rules if the flag exists. A bit nasty.

In case whatever you want to register can be registered after plugin activation, you can try a different approach.

`register_activation_hook()` internally registers an action hook on `activate_PLUGIN_NAME`. so what you can do, is to register your codes on the same hook with a higher precedence.

For example:

```
// __FILE__ is the main plugin file that contains the plugin headers.
$activation_hook = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );

// Register your stuff here, using a lower priority.
add_action( "activate_{$activation_hook}", "your_callback_to_register", 1, 1 );
```

Now, you can use `register_activation_hook()` freely, as it will run at a higher priority. Although pay attention, this hook might be too late to register certain stuff, but it works nicely for adding rewrite rules on plugin activation.

Answer (score 0):

What we need to do on plugin activation is this instead:

```
delete_option('rewrite_rules');
```